# Force applets to load in same JVM instance?

Tags: java, applet, jvm

I've taken over maintenance of an old web application, which uses multiple applets embedded in the same web page. This used to work fine, but since the Next Generation Java plugin was introduced (~1.6.0_10) the individual applets are not guaranteed to load in the same JVM instance. If they load in different JVMs, they cannot communicate through AppletContext.getApplets() or through static variables.

Is there any way we can force the applets to load in the same JVM instance? I saw a workaround mentioned where specifying identical 'java_arguments' parameter may encourage the Java plugin to run applets in the same JVM instance, but this does not work for our application (and in any case is not officially supported by Oracle and hence may disappear any time in any case).

We've also tried replacing direct applet-to-applet communication with indirect applet-to-JavaScript-to-applet communication, but we can't use this approach as our clients use old web browser versions which prevent this from working. I'd be keen to avoid routing all local applet-to-applet communication through a non-local server if at all possible.

Comment: They would all be in the same JVM if one 'controller applet' loaded all four of them into separate areas of its own content pane.  Why do the applets need to be embedded in a web page?

Comment: They need to be embedded in the page as each applet provides part of the page content, but separated by other items of 'normal' web content. Not a brilliant design, admittedly, but it's the one we've got. I'm hoping to replace all of the applets with JS equivalents eventually, but will have to do this one applet at a time.

Comment: I also thought Andrew Thompson's approach might be possible... Load the controller applet, load the sub-applets, load the page content into a panel that renders the normal web content? Do you have any control over that other content, the page layout, etc? Please list any other restrictions we must impose or can relax, no matter how obtuse :) Otherwise, if you aren't explicitly covered by http://www.java.net/node/695065, you may be SoL.

Comment: Thanks to both Andrew Thompson and ccoakley for your suggestions. I'll have a look and see if I can coax our app into working this way, with the controller applet and panels. Unfortunately we can't change the page layout and some of the applets are from other vendors, so I guess we might be SOL in the end :) Still, gives me a good justification to get on with the reworking.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @AndrewBurns unfortunately not, and I gave up; was starting to break for real-world users and we couldn't force them to reconfigure their Java setup. As a stopgap I modified the applets to bounce all inter-applet comms off the server, which bought enough time to rewrite the applet content in JS. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar problem and worked around it by disabling the "next-generation" Java plugin in Java control panel.

Comment: Thanks; just tried that, and it seemed to force everything into one VM. I don't think we'll be able to force our clients to do this however, as they are spread across a range of organisations and have locked-down workstations. So at least we've now got a last-resort workaround we can recommend to clients. If you hear of any other methods which don't need the user to change settings I'd be interested to know, as this would be a much easier sell.