# How to share data between applets in the same web page?

Tags: java, applet

I have several applets in the same web page and i would like to share data between them.

What is the best solution to do this ?

EDIT :

Thank you for your responses, I will try to be more specific :

I have 3 applets on my web page :

- first one will download files from the web server
- second one will be used to modify the files localy
- third one will send back modified files to the server

Each applet will work on the files and I would like to store path, name, and other properties of files in an object which would be shared between the applets.

The solution consisting of using Javascript to communicate between applets seems not very secure for my case.

I will read more about AppletContext.

Comment: You might be able to do it through javascript but I'm not quite sure because of the security implications.

Comment: Hope this link will be helpful:
[Communicating with other applets](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/communicating_with_other_applets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java<->JS is one well tried way to get information between applets, but see also the [`AppletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html).

> This interface corresponds to an applet's environment: **the document containing the applet and the *other applets* in the same document.**

It provides methods like:

- [`getApplet(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#getApplet%28java.lang.String%29)
- [`getApplets()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#getApplets%28%29)
- [`getStream(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#getStream%28java.lang.String%29)/`getStreams()`/`setStream(String,InputStream)`

A stream is a very generic and powerful way to exchange information.

Comment: All applets which may communicate must have the same jar as source

Comment: *"must have the same jar as source"*  That is not correct.  I've used applet<->applet communication using different applets deployed as loose class files.  It all comes down to whether the classes/jars are loaded in the same JVM - a separate matter.

Comment: I tried to use several jar but that didn't work. I assume that they were loaded in different JVM. I read [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780929/force-applets-to-load-in-same-jvm-instance) but that didn't work in my case.

Comment: You need to ask a new question about same/different JREs for applets. There are answers, but likely not as seen in the linked Q&A.